# jQuery: Make accordion list have 1 list item expanded already when page loads?

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code to display an accordion menu using jQuery.

Currently each item is closed (not expanded) when the page loads. I would like the first item in the list to already be expanded when the page loads. Is this possible to set somehow using jQuery?

Unfortunately I cannot change the HTML markup as it is being generated dynamically.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-classes" class="menu">
<li>
    <h3><a>Item 1</a></h3>
    <div class="sub">
        <p>Some blah blah here.</p>
        <a href="#"><span class="readmorehomebox">read more ›</span></a>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <h3><a>Item 2</a></h3>
    <div class="sub">
        <p>Some blah blah here.</p>
        <a href="#"><span class="readmorehomebox">read more ›</span></a>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <h3><a>Item 3</a></h3>
    <div class="sub">
        <p>Some blah blah here.</p>
        <a href="#"><span class="readmorehomebox">read more ›</span></a>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
  $('#menu-classes h3').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('.sub').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#menu-classes h3').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.sub {display: none;}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In document.ready just trigger a click on the one you want opened:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("selector for item you want open").click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot ad an ID to the first h3 because I can't change the HTML. How can I select it? I have tried adding `$("#menu-classes h3:first").click();` but this doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I tried adding it AFTER the first function closing brackets and the above worked!

Answer (score 0):

Give the element you want expanded an ID, and then simulate a click when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("some selector").click();
});
```

Also, it should be in a `ready` function, so that the element will exist when the page tries to *click* it.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean - but I can't change the HTML as it is being generate dynmically, so I can't add an ID. is it possible somehow to select the first h3?